# UK ancestry visa time for staying

Tags: ancestry

I just got approved for my uk ancestry visa I just wanted to know if I need to stay in the UK at least 6 continuous months each year or if I can leave, but I just can't be out of the country for more than 6 months at a time?

Comment: AFAIK there is no restriction. You would have needed to demonstrate your plans for employment as part of the application, would being absent for lengthy periods be possible if you’re working, given that you’re  not allowed to claim public funds? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/576708/UK-Ancestry-v16.pdf Do you intend to apply to settle in the UK? https://www.gov.uk/settle-in-the-uk If so, you’d need to take into account the rules around settlement and absence from the UK.

Comment: I would like to settle in the UK, It will just take me a year or 2 to settle my finances and other things in my country. So for the first year or 2 I would only be able to come every few months so I don't lose the visa. would this stop me from being able to settle in the uk after 5 years?

Comment: Yes. One of the eligibility criteria for settlement after 5 years is to have spent no more than 180 days outside the UK in any 12 months of the last 5 years (known as ‘continuous residence’) https://www.gov.uk/settle-in-the-uk/y/you-have-a-uk-ancestry-visa

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific restriction on the amount of time you must spend in the UK, unless you want to apply to settle after 5 years, in which case you must have spent no more than 180 days outside the UK in any 12 months of the last 5 years (known as ‘continuous residence’).

One aspect to consider is that the Immigration Rules relating to an Ancestry visa require you to demonstrate you can work and genuinely intend to take or seek employment in the UK. If your intended pattern of visits to the UK means that you won’t have a permanent job, you may find you are questioned by Immigration as to your intentions each time you return. If you don’t have employment, you are not allowed to claim public funds in the UK.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/576708/UK-Ancestry-v16.pdf